# C Programming Operations And value

Tags: c

The following code:

```
int z=10,y=5;
z=z&&!y;
printf("%d\n",z);
```

outputs 0. Can anyone explain how the result is 0?

Comment: What other result do you expect? and why?

Comment: Just a comment that it is often better to use () brackets and spacing in your mathematical expressions, it will make it much easier to read. That way, the precedence of operators is also clear. Example: If you write z = z && (!y); the intent of the expression becomes much clearer

Answer (score 3):

Logical NOT operator yields 0 if the operand is non-zero and 1 if the operand is `0`. Since `y` is 5, `!y` is `0`. Logical AND operator yields 0 or 1.

So, the entire expression `z && !y;` becomes `0` (which is assigned to `z` and `0` is printed).

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` is a boolean operation. In this context `0` means false and non-zero values mean true. Because of this `z&&!y` evaluates to `0`, and therefore 0 is assigned to `z`.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply z = 10 AND NOT(5)

10 is bigger than 0 so it evaluates to true. Not 5 will be 0, then 1 AND 0 will be 0!